# FilterPredicate Table by Colomn with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to filter my mat-table result by column using the predicate filter. Im already using a simple filter but it filtering all the data in all the column. I search for similar topics but i don't know how use it.
I try to repeat my code for all the column but doesn't work..

See code below :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <div class="example-header">
        <div>
            <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="aa">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>aa title</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.aa}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="bb">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> bb tilte </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.bb}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my **.ts** :

```
export class MynewComponent implements OnInit {
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    displayedColumns = ['aa', 'bb'];
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private materialService: MaterialService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.materialService.getUser().subscribe(value =>{this.dataSource.data = value;});
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
            this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
    }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    constructor(private materialService: MaterialService) {
        super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<MaterialModel[]> {
        return this.materialService.getUser();
    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**HTML** *Add 7 diff input fields also in `applyFilter` pass input value & a key of that column as string*

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'aa')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'bb')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'col3')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'col4')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'col5')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'col6')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value, 'col7')" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

> You can find other ways of writing HTML according to your requirement of design.

**component**

*Create filter obj having `key`: Column key & `value`: filter value*

```
filterObj = {};
applyFilter(filterValue: string, key: string) {
    this.filterObj = {
        value: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
        key: key
    }
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
        this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
}
```

*update `filterPredicate` as:*

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
    if(data[this.filterObj['key']] && this.filterObj['key']) {
        return data[this.filterObj['key']].toLowerCase().includes(this.filterObj['value']);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172503/discussion-on-answer-by-anshuman-jaiswal-filterpredicate-table-by-colomn-with-an).

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'key' does not exist on type '{}'. in my filterPredicate

Comment: Where to put the filterPredicate please ? do you have a working example ?

Comment: @Taieb you need to set it in datasource as written in the above example `this.dataSource.filterPredicate`

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, I have an API, which through him I'm getting my data.

I want at first to show all the table and be able to filter it with multiple filter. Do you have a working example please ?