# Multiple Filters with Angular Materials

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am working on an angular 8 project using angular materials for styling. I have used mat-table with filters for filtering data from the mat-table. The default mat-table filter filters data that contains entered characters. But I want to use two filters at a time with mat-table i.e. the default filter and a filter by domain (a column from the table) which will filter using dropdown. After research I found that I can filter data using columns by defining a filterPredicate which takes a column to filter but is there any way that I can use default filter and a column filter both together?

Below is my filter code with screenshots

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    if (this.search) {
      this.domainSelect = '';
    }
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

 // Below method is in complete and will be implemented for Domain Filter

  applyDomainFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(); 
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

[image: Mat-Table uses two filters 1.default Filter 2.ProjectDomain Filter]

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639972/9369606

Answer (score 0):

I always use one method for setting multiple filters determined by type string.

```
applyFilter(value: any, type: string) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'name':
      this.filterObject.name = value;
      break;
    case 'domain':
      this.filterObject.domain = value;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterObject);
}
```

In my filter predicate you can decide if you want to match exactly all or at least one filter. I always concat my filters with a logical `AND`.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (obj, filterStr) => {
  let filterObj = JSON.parse(filterStr);
  if(obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterObj.name.toLowerCase()) && obj.domain.toLowerCase().includes(filterObj.domain.toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is filterObject ?